# Making a <div> or <td> with the same effect as <input type="color"/> using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made an example of input type="color" here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/u3at1s8f/

HTML

```
<body id="bg">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">
        <input type="color" id="inputcol" />
      </td>
      <td id="tdcol" class="two">
        Change colour
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td class="two">
        lorem
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

CSS

```
input {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: red;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#inputcol:hover, #tdcol:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".one").css("background-color", $("#inputcol").val());
});

$("#inputcol").on("change", function() {
  $(".one").css("background-color", $("#inputcol").val());
});

$("#tdcol").on("click", function() {
  /* color-function */
});
```

The reason I want this functionality in a div/td is because I want to remove all the borders of the button, and to be able to put text on it as well. Right now there is a weird white and gray border around the button and no text.

Is this possible to simulate this behaviour on a div/td by using a javascript function?

Comment: unexplained downvote?

Comment: You can set `background-color: transparent` to clear the large grey area. I've not found which CSS rule is leaving the gray outline though.

Comment: _"The reason I want this functionality"_ ? Which one ?

Comment: @Rayon I want the button with the functionality of a div/td, that would mean both text and no borders?

Comment: Yes, this can be done. It's substantial without recommending a library (which is off-topic), too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

`input type=color` is a browser depended feature http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color.

I would use a more reliable jQuery plug-in. Simple googling gave me https://github.com/PitPik/tinyColorPicker, http://www.dematte.at/colorPicker/ and many others

If you don't like border of the input, just change `css` for that input.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use labels to achieve this. See the example updated in Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u3at1s8f/1/

```
         <label for=color>Change color
               <input type=color id=color style="position: absolute; top: -100%">
         </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can trigger the `click` event on another (possibly hidden) `input type="color"`

```
$("#tdcol").on("click", function() {
  /* color-function */
  $("#inputcol2").click();
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this working, but that seems like a good solution.